# How should I reset a JPA-controlled database before every test?

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, jpa, integration-testing

Is there a best-practice pattern for completely resetting a database to a freshly-paved schema with JPA before a unit test? I have been using a testing persistence unit with hbml2ddl.auto=create-or-drop and recreating EMFs before each test, but I wonder if there's a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: What is a testing persistence unit? What is an EMF? How are you recreating before each test?

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should not talk to the database.

Assuming you're writing an integration test for your data access layer, you could use a tool like [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/), or you could create a static test helper that programmatically resets your database state by doing all of your deletes and inserts using JPA queries inside of a transaction.

Comment: Could you justify your initial assertion?

Comment: I guess the justification is 'because databases are slow'. This is true when using Oracle and so on, where even opening a connection is slow. It's not true for in-memory databases.

Comment: I guess the justification is that "unit" tests are supposed to test "units" in isolation. As soon as you're involving a database, you're not doing unit testing but integration testing. It has nothing to do with the kind of database that is used.

Comment: I agree in principle that unit tests generally don't connect with the database, but I'd also add that unit tests shouldn't cross process boundaries. Thus if you require a database to be started up in another process then you're in the realms of integration testing. However if there is minimal effort in getting an in-memory database working for you, then it might be cheaper to do so than using mocks.

Comment: Using Mockito or JMock is pretty "cheap". Your data access code should have integration tests that hit the database. In this case, I prefer to hit the real database so that I'm really testing the integration. But it's usually unnecessary to test your business logic with any kind of database (in-memory or otherwise) since mocking frameworks are so easy to use nowadays.

Comment: It's not called a unit test if it interacts with the database, it's an integration tests.  Once you get in this mindset you realize that Unit testing is much less useful than you used to think.  A give "Unit Test" only tests one method/class at a time.  If your test chains to other "Units", it's an integration test or a system test.   Integration tests are often run with JUnit as well, so they often get called unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the database is not a big problem if you use a fast Java database such as the [H2 database](http://h2database.com) or HSQLDB. Compared to using Oracle / MySQL (or whatever you use for production) this will speed up your tests, and it will ensure all your code is tested as when using the 'real' production database.

For maximum performance, you can use H2 in-memory (that way you may not have to reset the database manually - it's reset automatically if the connection is closed), or you can use a regular persistent database. To reset the database after use in H2, run the (native) statement 'drop all objects delete files'.

Comment: how do you force the connection to close?

Comment: An H2 database does not verify that your code will work on a production database, since h2 varies from i.e. a mysql database in multiple ways.

Comment: @Maaaaa I assume if somebody uses JPA, then he wants to write database-type independent code. In other words, it is true that H2 and MySQL have different behavior, but so do different versions of Java have different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

DBUnit has much of what you need, I use Springs Testing framework to rollback, transactions after each test see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a best-practice pattern for completely resetting a database to a freshly-paved schema with JPA before a unit test?

Don't reset the whole DB schema before every unit test, but reset the "DB environment (which is specific to the current unit test)" at END of each unit test.

We have an entity...

```
@Entity
public class Candidate implements {
    private String id;
    private String userName;
    private EntityLifeCycle lifeCycle;

    protected Candidate() {
    }
    public Candidate(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator="uuid", strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy="uuid", parameters = {})
    @Column(name="candidate_id", nullable=false, unique=true)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    protected void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="user_name", nullable=false, unique=true)
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Embedded
    public EntityLifeCycle getLifeCycle() {
        if(lifeCycle == null) {
            lifeCycle = new EntityLifeCycleImpl();
        }
        return lifeCycle;
    }
    public void setLifeCycle(EntityLifeCycleImpl lifeCycle) {
        this.lifeCycle = lifeCycle;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
         lifeCycle.setCreatedDate(new Date());
    }
}
```

We are setting the createdDate for each Candidate instance in prePersist() method. Here is a test case that asserts that createdDate is getting set properly....

```
   public class EntityLifeCycleTest {
    @Test
    public void testLifeCycle() {
        EntityManager manager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        Candidate bond = new Candidate("Miss. Bond");
        EntityTransaction tx = manager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        manager.persist(bond);
        tx.commit();

        Assert.assertNotNull(bond.getLifeCycle().getCreatedDate());
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

This test case will run properly for the first time. But if we run this test case second time it would throw ConstraintViolationException, because the userName is unique key.

Therefore, I think the right approach is to "clean the DB environment (which is specific to the current unit test)" at end of each test case. Like this...

```
public class EntityLifeCycleTest extends JavaPersistenceTest {
    @Test
    public void testLifeCycle() {
        EntityManager manager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        Candidate bond = new Candidate("Miss. Bond");
        EntityTransaction tx = manager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        manager.persist(bond);
        tx.commit();

        Assert.assertNotNull(bond.getLifeCycle().getCreatedDate());

      /* delete Candidate bond, so next time we can run this test case successfully*/
        tx = manager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        manager.remove(bond);
        tx.commit();
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

> I have been using a testing persistence unit with hbml2ddl.auto=create-or-drop and recreating EMFs before each test, but I wonder if there's a cleaner way to do it.

Recreating EMF before each test is time consuming, IMO.

Drop and recreate the DB schema only if you have made some changes to @Entity annotated class that affects the underlying DB (e.g. adding/removing columns and/or constraints). So first validate the schema, if the schema is valid don't recreate it, and if invalid then recreate it. Like this...

```
public class JavaPersistenceTest {
    protected static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    if(entityManagerFactory == null) {
         Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
         try {
           properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
          entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default", properties);
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default", properties);
    }
         }
}
}
```

Now, if you run all the test cases(that extend JavaPersistenceTest) in one go, the EMF will be created only once(or twice if the schema was invalid).

Comment: I don't agree, [Good setup don't need cleanup!](http://www.dbunit.org/bestpractices.html#nocleanup)

Comment: @PascalThivent It is not always true. If there is e.g. a test for a findAll() method and I would like to be sure there is no more record in the database than I expect, then yes, I would like clean up all other records before this test. Even if that db is mine, I would like keep it as clear as it is needed.